# How do I export a SimpleSwingApplication as an executable JAR with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, swing, scala, classpath, executable-jar

I am trying to export a `SimpleSwingApplication` as an executable JAR with Eclipse:

```
package gui

import scala.swing._

object Startup extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  // ...
}
```

However, when I choose Export.../Java/JAR file and come to the part where I have to pick the Main class, Eclipse doesn't seem to be able to find one. Manually typing in `gui.Startup` doesn't help.

I thought maybe that's because `Startup` is an object instead of a class, or maybe it has to do with inheriting the `main` method instead of providing one yourself. But even this simple code fails to export:

```
package gui

class Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hello")
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could be a bug - your `object Startup` is perfectly executable main class. You can try exporting your jar without choosing main class, and add it to manifest later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your own manifest file, and specify the main class yourself.  When you export the jar file, eclipse will have a screen where you can select your own manifest file instead of generating one.

This example manifest should do the trick:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```